# Remove particular device from deployment target iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

An app that I am working on is having memory issues with UIKit caching of images on the first retina iPod touch (4th generation).

I was just wondering if there is a way for me to make sure 4th gen. iPod touch users cannot see my app in the appstore?

Comment: let me guess: you have huge images, that you just assign to a UIImageView and than scale that, right?

Comment: @vikingosegundo No, its just a lot of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to explicitly exclude a certain device (by the device type/name) from being supported by your app.

You can however request certain capabilities from your device in the project's Info.plist file, so that if the device doesn't offer such capabilities, it will be excluded from the list of supported devices in your app.

You need to modify your Info.plist file's "Required Device Capabilities" array.

Look for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the following link to see what capabilities you can request:

[Link to developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

To exclude all iPods you could try requesting one of these: telephony, sms, gps.

Keep in mind that this method makes it easy to exclude a full family of devices, but it may get tricky to exclude a particular device by it's "generation" number (ie. the 4th gen iPod).